# In a ring R with unity, let z$\in$M, M a unital left R-module, showing $_RR$/$Ann_R$(z) is isomorphic to <z>_R

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I recently came across this problem during my study of modules:
"Let R be a ring with unity and M a unital left R-module. For z$\in$M, let $_R$ denote the R-submodule of M generated by Z. Show $_RR$/$Ann_R(z) \cong_R$(z)$_R$, i.e. they are isomorphic as left R-modules."

My attempt so far has been to define $\phi$:$_RR \rightarrow$$_R$ by $\phi(r)=rz$. I've shown $\phi$ is an R-module homomorphism and that $ker(\phi)=Ann_R(z)$. I want to show that $\phi$ is onto so that I can use the First Isomorphism Theorem. However, with the definition I was given of (z)$_R$={rz+nz:r$\in$R and n$\in \mathbb{Z}$}, I am having trouble showing $\phi$ is onto.

Am I missing something trivial, or is my idea entirely wrong? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: For every $r \in R$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$, 
$$
rz+nz = rz+n(1_Rz) = rz+(n1_R)z = (r+n1_R)z.
$$
So, $_R(z) \subseteq \{az : a \in R\}$.
On the other hand, for every $a \in R$,
$$
az = az+0z,
$$
and so $\{az : a \in R\} \subseteq \! {}_R(z)$.

Comment: Oh I see, because n$1_R$ is $1_R+1_R+…+1_R$ n many times, which is an element of R! Thank you so much!